# MongoDb Driver C# ¿Cómo acceder a una lista de documentos basado en los ids guardados en un array dentro de un objeto de un documento?

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, asp.net, mongodb, sql

Quisiera formular una pregunta respecto a una consulta en una DB de MongoDb utilizando el Driver para C#.

Tengo las siguientes clases:

```
class Persona {
     string _id {get; set;}
     IEnumerable<Dispositivo> dispositivos {get; set;}
     ...
}

class Dispositivo {
     string _id {get; set;}
     string nombre {get; set;}
     string IEnumerable<ObjectId> trazasGPS {get; set;}
     ...
}

class TrazasGPS {
     string _id {get; set;}
     long latitud {get; set;}
     long longitud {get; set;}
     DateTime fechaCreacion {get; set;}
     ...
}
```

en Base de datos esto resulta en

```
//Documento Persona
{
     "_id": ObjectId(sfasfasf...),
     "dispositivos ": [
            {"_id": sfasff3asf...,
            "trazasGPS ": [
                   ObjectId("dsafsdfasd435sasdf"),
                   ObjectId("dsafsdffgg435sasdf"),
                   ObjectId("dsafsdfasddhfgasdf"),
                   ...
            ]},
            {"_id": sfasd3asf...,
            "trazasGPS ": [
                   ObjectId("dsafsdfasd43sdffdf"),
                   ObjectId("dsafsdasdf435sasdf"),
                   ...
            ]}
     ]
}

//Documento TrazasGPS
{
     "_id": ObjectId(fdgsdfgsdfdsdfgdfg),
     "latitud": 1234561232435,
     "longitud": 1234561254335,
     "fechaCreacion": "2020-10-12T23:23:59",
}
```

¿Existe alguna forma eficiente de obtener las trazasGPS entre fechaA y FechaB, que se encuentren dentro de la colección de **trazasGPS** de una **persona** en un **dispositivo** específico?

Actualmente lo que estoy haciendo es:

```
Dispositivo d = ColeccionPersona.AsQueryable().Select(persona => persona.Objetivo.Where(dispositivo._id.Equals("sdasdfasdf") && persona._id.Equals("sdfasdfasdf))).FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault()

string[] ids = new string[d.trazasGPS.Count()];
for(int i = 0; i < d.trazasGPS.Count(); i++) {
    ids[i] = ((List<ObjectId>)d.trazasGPS)[i].ToString(); }

var timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime();
timestamp = timestamp -(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2); //48 horas antes

var filter = Builders<TrazasGPS>.Filter.In(traza._id, ids) & Builders<TrazasGPS>.Filter.Gt("fechaCreacion", DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(timestamp), DateTimeKind.Local));

List<TrazasGPS> trazas = ColeccionTrazasGPS.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Funciona, pero es muy ineficiente. Obtengo un dispositivo específico, de una persona específica, que puede tener una lista de 10.000 ObjectId's, la coloco en memoria, itero sobre ella y luego hago una segunda consulta. Me gustaría poder obtener los datos en una sola consulta, y que la base de datos se encargue de devolver la lista de documentos trazaGPS.

¿Existe en C# alguna manera de conseguirlo?

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Sigo aún sin conseguir avanzar. ¿Alguna idea?